# Is $f: ( \mathbb{ Z}_{10},+) \rightarrow ( \mathbb{ Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{ Z}_{2},+), n\pmod {10} \mapsto (n \pmod 5,n \pmod 2) $ surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is $f: ( \mathbb{ Z}_{10},+) \rightarrow ( \mathbb{ Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{ Z}_{2},+), n\pmod {10} \mapsto (n \pmod 5,n \pmod 2) $ surjective?

If I take an element in $\mathbb{ Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{ Z}_{2}$, say $(p,q)=f(n)$ I have to check this equation has always a solution for any value of p and q

so  $([p]_5,[q]_2)=([n]_5,[n]_2)$

then I don't now how to continue. any help please?

Comment: The target group has only ten elements; you could check them all....

Answer (score 1):

So you want an $x \in \Bbb{Z}_{10}$ such that
\begin{align*}
x &\equiv a \pmod{5}\\
x &\equiv b \pmod{2}
\end{align*}
So $x=a+5k=b+2s$ for some $s,k \in \Bbb{Z}$. Thus $\boxed{5k-2s=b-a}$. But $\gcd(2,5)=1$ so we can express
\begin{align*}
5(1)-2(2)&=1\\
5(b-a)-2(2b-2a)&=b-a.
\end{align*}
So if we take $k=b-a$ (*see boxed equation and the last equation above*) we get $x=a+5(b-a)=\color{red}{5b-4a}$. You can verify that
$$f(5b-4a)=([a]_{5},[b]_2)$$

In general use Chinese Remainder theorem.

Comment: why is $1=b-a$?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO We have the relation $5(1)-2(2)=1$, then we multiply both sides by some integer say $c$, to get $5(c)-2(2c)=1(c)=c$. In our case, $c$ happens to be $b-a$.